# Google does not return nearest places

Tags: java, google-maps

Currently I am having an issue while using the Google Places API when searching with a 'nearby search' for specific places.

I use the parameter `rankby=distance` which should deliver the nearest places first, but I only get the nearest ones when I use the next page token which I get after the first request. 
That means:

1. First query delivers places greater than 7 kilometres (example)
2. Second query (with next page token from the first one) delivers
   places < 4km.

So the second one should actually be the first one. I hope you understand the problem. 
My query looks like this (nothing special...):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=<lat>,<long>&key=<mykey>&language=en&keyword=<mykeyword>&rankby=distance
```

And the second one with the next page token 
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=<lat>,<long>&key=<mykey>&pagetoken=CRPADFKALsomeTokenExample`

Comment: Could it be that Google places some (paid) results before the organic ones?

Comment: I do not think so